# How do I make a Hyperlink pulse (i.e. fade in and out endlessly) on an aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-animate

Hello I have a regular website, and I am adding a new link to the top navigation bar. To alert users of the new button, I would like it to pulse gently, quite like the pulsing light on the Macbook Air when the lid is closed :)

here is what the Hyperlink code looks like:

```
<td class="data" runat="server" style="width: 85px">
   <asp:HyperLink ID="SiteLink"  runat="server" CssClass="anc" Text="NEW LINK" />
</td>
```

I have jQuery in my project already, so either jQuery or plain JS will work fine. The solution needs to work in IE and Chrome. I tried jquery.pulse but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works:

```
function cycle() {
    $('#SiteLink').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#SiteLink').fadeIn(1000);
        cycle();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    cycle();
});
```

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/m8qanvr3/

Comment: Thanks, that was awesome :) Is there a way to add delay after the first cycle? I don't want it to be fading in and out continuously. I would like a 5-second delay